# Is there any reason you would not want to change values on a class of an element rather than the style object?

Tags: html, css, dom, layout, html-rendering

Is there any reason you would not want to apply a class to an element and then modify the class?

For example, let's say you were going to have a dynamic scale value that you can change to any value using a slider. You could change that using the following:

```
var value = mySlider.value;
element.style.transform = "scale(.532)";
```

and update it that way.

But what if you created a class like this:

```
.myElementScale {
    transform: scale(.532);
}
```

And added it to the element. Then when you changed the slider value you updated the class declaration:

```
var declaration = getStyleDeclaration(".myElementScale"); //pseudo code 
declaration.setStyle("transform", "scale(.532)");
```

Is there any reason not to do this? I ask because I have not seen anyone else doing this and wonder if there are performance issues with it. I'd rather not set styles directly but the style value can be dynamic so it has to be set somewhere.

Comment: You mean aside from it being more convoluted? I think that the implementation of `getStyleDeclaration(".myElementScale")` was historically tricky to get right cross-browser, but I doubt it's a problem in modern browsers. Performance? Yeah what the browser would have to do internally would be quite different, in terms of recomputing the cascade, and like all performance things you really have to measure it for your particular case.

Comment: @Alohci right. That's what I was thinking too. Internal cascade and things. What would you? Right now I'm cluttering up the markup by setting the style directly and by setting the style object it's taking higher priority over class values. I might do some performance tests.

Comment: I would use a dictionary to keep a reference to the style declaration so that wouldn't be an issue. Also, the style declaration would be only for that element. So changing no other elements (besides descendants) would be affected.

Comment: *I would use a dictionary except that I don't think you can store elements as keys.

Comment: I tested setting both the `element.style` property and the style declaration object assigned to the element and they were about the same at about average of 3ms - 7ms total for the DOM Event (1.57ms), then the paint (1.73ms), then recalculate style (3.73ms), a second recalculate style (.91ms), and finally apply style changes (0ms) layout 3 times at .16ms,.04ms,.02ms. It seems setting the style object takes longer by a millisecond or 2 but based on only my few tests.